# Make Home Partition Size Larger and Reduce Root Partition Size

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

My Root Partition is of 418 GB and the home partition is of 464 GB. My Home Partition is now almost full while the Root Partition is only 20 GB used. So, I want to Decrease size of Root Partition and Increase Home Partition Size.

I found a similar question in which root partition was to be increased and home to be decreased. But, the answers to that question were short.
[image]

It would be helpful for me if someone guide me step by step to change my partition sizes and how to use chroot to fix fstab (if the UUID partition changes). I am not familiar to chroot and how to use it in live session.

Comment: Resizing a partition will not change it's UUID.

Comment: @mook765 thanks for confirming it. Actually, I had no option for backup data. That's why I wanted to know the fix if UUID changes. After your confirmation, I tried resizing both partitions and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Having no option to backup data means living with the permanent risk of data loss. You should really think about that. A backup is a must, at least for data you cannot risk to lose. If we lose our OS, it's not too painfull, we can reinstall. But our personal data, once lost, can only be recreated from backup. Please keep that in mind.

Comment: The move left of /home into the space you made by shrinking /  is the most dangerous change. It has to copy data from one area on drive to another. We recently had several posts where users had power failures of some sort in the middle of that change. Then there is no way to recover partitions and just about no way to recover data. Another alternative is to just make another partition and use it for some of the data in /home. But backup still important.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Backup is important and I should have taken it. I do not have any extra hard disk or storage option for backup. That's why I took the risk.
If someone is reading this question, kindly take the proper backup as things might not go well with you and data will be lost.
I do not encourage anyone to change their partitions without having a proper backup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **resize** the right side of /dev/nvme0n1p2 to the desired size (~70G)
- **move** /dev/nvme0n1p3 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/nvme0n1p3 all the way right
- click the Apply icon